# Why might one also use a blank constructor?

Tags: java, coding-style, constructor

I was reading some Java recently and came across something (an idiom?) new to me: in the program, classes with multiple constructors would also always include a blank constructor. For example:

```
public class Genotype {
  private boolean bits[];
  private int rating;
  private int length;
  private Random random;

  public Genotype() {              //  <= THIS is the bandit, this one right here
    random = new Random();
  }

  /* creates a Random genetoype */
  public Genotype(int length, Random r) {
    random = r;
    this.length = length;
    bits = new boolean[length];

    for(int i=0;i<length;i++) {
        bits[i] =random.nextBoolean();
    }
  }

  /* copy constructor */
  public Genotype(Genotype g,Random r) {
    random = r;
    bits = new boolean[g.length];
    rating = g.rating;
    length = g.length;

    for(int i=0;i<length;i++) {
        bits[i] = g.bits[i];
    }

  }
}
```

The first constructor doesn't seem to be a "real" constructor, it seems as though in every case one of the other constructors will be used. So why is that constructor defined at all?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am not sure that the code you were reading was high quality (I've reviewed some bioinformatics code in the past and it is unfortunately often not written by professional developers). For example, that third constructor is not a copy constructor and generally there are problems in this code, so I wouldn't "read too much into it".

The first constructor is a default constructor. It only initializes the bare minimum and lets users set the rest with getters and setters. Other constructors are often "convenience constructors" that help create objects with less calls. However, this can often lead to inconsistencies between constructors. In fact, there is recent research that shows that a default constructor with subsequent calls to setters is preferable.

There are also certain cases where a default constructor is critical. For example, certain frameworks like digester (used to create objects directly from XML) use default constructors. JavaBeans in general use default constructors, etc.

Also, some classes inherit from other classes. you may see a default constructor when the initialization of the parent object is "good enough".

In this specific case, if that constructor was not defined, one would have to know all the details in advance. That is not always preferable.

And finally, some IDEs automatically generate a default constructor, it is possible that whoever wrote the class was afraid to eliminate it.

Comment: What does the research say? I usually write only as many constructors as I need (this tends to be one), but I saw some code on stackoverflow that went something like, `CoffeeCup mug = new cupBuilder().setShape(fat).setPractical(true).setHandle(true).build()`is this what you are talking about?

Comment: Yes, except that you don't chain them on one call but rather have multiple calls.

Comment: Here's an academic paper about it: Jeffrey Stylos and Steven Clarke. "Usability Implications of Requiring Parameters in Objects' Constructors". International Conference on Software Engineering (ICSE 2007). http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~NatProg/papers/Stylos2007CreateSetCall.pdf

Comment: +1 for the paper. The one problem I have with it is that it doesn't take into account how much time and pain is spent with runtime defects for each case. Sometimes the compiler / language constrains me in ways that I don't like and slows me down, but the payoff is huge compared to tracking down problems in a live runtime scenario. So, if there is information that the class MUST have to operate and trying do use it without that information would cause strange behaviour then parameters in the constructor seem to make sense to me.

Comment: That is, coding quickly and happily doesn't always equal better code.

Answer (score 5):

Is the object [Serializable](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)?

> To allow subtypes of non-serializable classes to be serialized, the subtype may assume responsibility for saving and restoring the state of the supertype's public, protected, and (if accessible) package fields. The subtype may assume this responsibility only if the class it extends has an accessible no-arg constructor to initialize the class's state. It is an error to declare a class Serializable if this is not the case. The error will be detected at runtime.
>
> During deserialization, the fields of non-serializable classes will be initialized using the public or protected no-arg constructor of the class. A no-arg constructor must be accessible to the subclass that is serializable. The fields of serializable subclasses will be restored from the stream

Comment: Only the most derived non-serialisable superclass must have a no-args constructor. It is a common mistake to think that serailisable classes need a no-args constructor.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I agree the "blank" constructor should not always exist (in my experience beginners often make this mistake), although there are cases when blank constructor would suffice. However if the blank constructor violates the invariant that **all the members are properly instantiated after construction**, blank constructor should not be used. If the constructor is complicated, it is better to divide the construction into several protected/private methods. Then use a **static** method or another **Factory** class to call the protected methods for construction, as needed.

What I wrote above is the ideal scenario. However, frameworks like spring remove the constructor logic out of the code and into some xml configuration files. You may have getter and setter functions, but probably may be avoided from the interface, [as described here](http://sbtourist.blogspot.com/2006/07/avoid-your-getters-and-setters-part-1.html).

Answer (score 2):

Default constructor is NOT mandatory.

If no constructors defined in the class then default (empty) constructor will be created automatically. If you've provided any parametrized constructor(s) then default constructor will not be created automatically and it's better to create it by yourself. Frameworks that use dependency injection and dynamic proxy creation at runtime usually require default constructor. So, it depends on use cases of class that you write.

Answer (score 0):

The default constructor is'nt a good pratice for the functional view.
The default constructor is used if the object have a global visibility into a method: for example, you want log the actual state of a object in a try/catch
you can code

```
MyObejct myObject=null
try{...
}catch(Exception e){
    log.error(myObject);//maybe print null. information?
}
```

or do you prefer

```
MyObejct myObject=new Object();
try{...
}catch(Exception e){
log.error(myObject);//sure print  myobject.toString, never null. More information
}
```

?

Anotherway the create a EMPTY object have'nt a lot of logic, but instatiate a NULL object is harmuful in my opinion.
You can read [this post](http://www.basilv.com/psd/blog/2008/how-to-handle-null-values-in-code)

Answer (score 0):

That is NOT a copy constructor. Basically you want empty constructors when working with some framework. Shall there always be an empty constructor, of course, public or private, but at least it allows you to keep control of how the class is being (or not) instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

I usually write one constructor that fully initializes the object; if there are others, they all call this(...) with appropriate defaults.

An object should be 100% initialized and ready for use when it's created.

Some frameworks, for example Hibernate, demand a no-arg constructor.  The way they clash with best practices makes me uneasy sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Having a default and empty (blank) constructor prevents you from having any final fields. This leads to a lot of mutability where there it is often not needed.

The builder pattern allows you to mix these two styles and allow more flexible initialization while still having immutability by hiding a many-arg constructor behind the factory.

Answer (score 0):

For some POJO classes or simple class, default constructor is useful when you sometimes want to do unit testing on the class using them. You don't need to mock them, you can new an object with default constructor and test the value set and get from them or pass them as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a blank constructor for the classes that extended this 
class and since it has been extended the class... the child now has super which references the class above it it's parent. In the event the child did not specify super(stuff)... the stuff inside to reference the other constructors to use it will now attempt to reference the empty constructor.

I'm not sure what the error will be I am coding my first parent object relationship now and was looking up things here ha cheers.

I guess I should add the moment you make a constructor that isn't the empty one you lose the default empty one so now super() which is default in the extended class won't have something to point to. Of course if you created the extended classes to take care of super by specifying on which gets rid of the default super() then you sidestep this but what if someone wants to use your class and extend from it and didn't realize there isn't an empty set when you could have 
just created one.

This is my first post but wanted to take a crack from how I understand it.