# How to best explain and use empty Constructors in Java?

Tags: java, constructor

I have been self-learning Java. I understand the scope of defining a class, but still didn't get the concept of an empty constructor usage.
Usually we should pass parameters for constructor to build instance object. But, I often see empty parameter for constructor. For example:

```
 class Person {
   String name;
       int age; 

 public Person();

 public Person(String name, int age){
     this.name = name;
     this.age = age;
     } 
 }
```

I researched and read an example that using a class "fish" to explain. So, this is what I understood so far: when defining a class, we first define properties for an object, then we create a constructor that will build the object with methods. Empty constructor build GENERIC object, and constructor with parameters build objects with more specific information. Let’s say the example above, if I create an instance object using the empty constructor:

```
Person p1 = new Person();
```

-- it will still create an object but without any properties in it? 
So, what exactly the empty constructor is used for? I saw it in a lot of example codes. Is it very useful/common?

Thanks for looking and answering!

Comment: You probably want your constructors *inside* your class.

Comment: @tbodt, please don't "fix" their code by editing the OP

Comment: Nobody voted for an answer? That's surprising.

Comment: @tbodt: Each answer has a different puzzle piece.  I didn't vote for your answer because it uses technical terms ("default," "initialize", 
"scope") that you didn't explain, which the OP is unlikely to know at his level of knowledge.

Comment: @RobertHarvey If all the answers are helpful, vote for all of them. If only some of the answers are helpful, vote for those. Alternatively, write your own answer that you think is more helpful than all the others.

Comment: @tbodt: No. But thank you for the suggestion anyway.  I could write a book-length answer to this question, but I think I'll leave it to the books.

Answer (score 17):

If you write a constructor with parameters, then you need to declare the default one (if you want to use it)

```
class Person {
    String name;
    int age; 

    public Person(String name, int age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    } 
 }
```

You **can't** do this now:

```
Person p = new Person();
```

In order to use the "default" constructor (with no parameters) you will need to declare it:

```
class Person {
    String name;
    int age; 

    public Person(){
        name = "Man With No Name";  //sometimes you will want to set the variables 
        age = 21;     //to some default values
    }

    public Person(String name, int age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    } 
 }
```

Comment: The downvoter care to explain his/her logic ?

Comment: It wasn't my downvote, but looking at your answer, it seems as if you're explaining under what conditions parameterless constructors need to be declared, and not why you might use them (which is what the OP asked for).

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm just pointing out that, if you have a constructor with parameters, you need to explicitly declare the default no-parameters one if you want to use it.

Comment: Yes, I know.  But we insist that answers actually answer the question being asked.  We're kinda funny that way.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The answer could be, "sometimes, you want to have a default constructor to set the variables to some default values", and I think my answer does answer the question.

Answer (score 11):

There are three common reasons to define a default constructor:

- To construct an object with default values.
- To initialize an object that doesn't need parameters in that initialization process.
- To redefine the scope of the constructor. Making the constructor private will prevent anyone but the class itself from constructing an object.

Answer (score 4):

I am sure other answers would come but in short -

Empty constructor just gives you an instance of that object. You might use setters on it to set necessary properties. If you want to make sure that any instance created is always valid and any member variables are always initialized,then you would define the constructor which initializes all the required member variables.

Also if you use frameworks like Spring, default constructor is often used where properties are set using setter injection.

Comment: EDIT: Here is other SO question on same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402514/why-might-one-also-use-a-blank-constructor

Answer (score 3):

A lot of software written in java these days takes advantage of frameworks that operate directly on your code at runtime by using special JVM features (known as reflection) to just access your class directly and mess around with it, rather than access it through the code you actually wrote.

One common example of such a library is Hibernate.  It "magically" takes information from a relational database and assigns the database values to the fields of an object.  Your class is enhanced with additional code added at run time to make it magically map back to the contents of the database.

It is a consequence of the reflection API that it's a real pain in the butt to work with classes that do not have a 'default' constructor.  You would have to supply a lot of additional information about how to correctly use your class's constructors in a way that can be programmatically interpreted.

Instead, the tools just require that classes have an empty, default, constructor, to make it easy to enhance the class at runtime.

Hence, we tend to leave an empty constructor always, even when creating an object without supplying certain values doesn't really make sense according to our program's API.

Comment: It's very easy to work with classes that have nondefault constructors with reflection. What is **not** easy is getting parameter names for those constructors (since those get stripped out by the compiler), making it impossible to automagically match up, say, database columns with constructor params. (Not without requiring programmers to annotate all their entity constructor params.)

Comment: I do not understand how your comment is different from what I said....

Comment: What I'm saying is that there is no particular difficulty in using nondefault constructors via reflection, if you can match their parameters with what you need to pass in - like, say, using the parameter **types**, which are readily available. Hibernate is a special case in that matching by type would be only marginally useful there. (By contrast, Spring supports and in fact promotes auto-wiring by type, so implementing this would be trivial and I wouldn't be surprised if they actually do.)

Comment: Another problem with Hibernate, specifically, in that Hibernate frequently needs to connect object graphs that aren't acyclic. E.g. if you have the constructors `Car(Engine engine)`, and `Wheel(Car car)`, you have a problem. Hibernate would now have to inspect the available ways to instantiate entities and construct a dependency graph and yell when it finds a cycle etc. Spring is, again, a good contrast: handling this dependency tree is core to what Spring does, and coding against interfaces would theorethically let them support cycles in it (although they don't).

Comment: So, your analysis seems limited to the problems Hibernate would face, when there are possibly plenty of use cases when those wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

An empty constructor usually is "a default"

```
Person() { 
    // This will cause you to not have any name or age values
}
```

So let's assume you want a default Person:

```
Person() { 
    this("Steven",20);
}
```

This way you will call the non empty constructor but you will always have the same person

Comment: What does "default" mean?  What is meaningful about a "default person"?

Comment: In this case, a 20 years old person called Steven would be "my default", I mean, the default for my class Person

Comment: Would that be useful in any way?  I'm reminded of the multiple Agent Smith's from the second Matrix movie.

Comment: Well, if we develop a Matrix game this may be useful.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: If you replace the `name` and `age` attribute with `arms` and `legs`, having default values means that you don't have to specify that a default person has two arms and two legs, even though you support persons having 3 arms and 1 leg. 

Edit: ...or maybe you just really like 20 year old Stevens - what do I know? ;)

Comment: @lzmaki That's arguably a better example than the one presented here.

Comment: +1 Because I don't think this answer deserved the downvote

Comment: @anakata: A pretty poor reason to upvote, but whatev.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I am aware that the whole stackexchange system is to generate useful complete answers, but I think you are being overly picky (if you were the downvoter)

Comment: Of course it is a better example, however, the question is using a Person with only Name and Age attirbutes.

Comment: The practice of returning default constants in an empty constructor is a very non-expressive way to program and could easily get confusing later on. It makes sense to set default values to things internal to the class, but I would argue not for values that are being served to customers.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you define an "empty" (default) constructor or not allows you to make clear to yourself and other developers, if certain fields are required to be set or not. (If the constructor demands them, they're required.)

Some libraries (for example Google GSON, ORMs ...) require you to have an empty constructor, but that's rather for technical reasons.

Another thing to keep in mind is that you can usually declare the fields assigned through a constructor as `final`, both for optimization and to make clear that they won't change during the object's lifetime.

But that all depends on the situation and what you're trying to do.